# How to install robotnik Summit-xl stack?

Tags: ros, installation, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all. As stated in the title, I am trying to install Summit-xl from robotnik. First I downloaded the tar.gz file from its [website](http://code.google.com/p/summit-xl-ros-stack/). Then I extracted it out to my sandbox and try to rosmake it. However, rosmake have been unsuccessful,

```
chengxiang@ubuntu:~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox$ rosmake fuerte
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['fuerte']                                  
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/chengxiang/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output- 
20121202-143919
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['fuerte'] to:
['summit_xl_description', 'summit_xl_odometry', 'summit_xl_tf',  
'summit_xl_2dnav', 'robotnik_worlds', 'summit_xl_sbpl_nav', 'explore_stage', 
'explore', 'summit_xl_joystick', 'summit_xl_ctrl']
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> colladadom [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< geometry_msgs  No Makefile in package geometry_msgs    
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< sensor_msgs  No Makefile in package sensor_msgs        
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> summit_xl_joystick [ make ]                            
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< colladadom ROS_NOBUILD in package colladadom           
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pr2_hardware_interface [ make ]                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pr2_hardware_interface ROS_NOBUILD in package  
pr2_hardware_interface
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> urdf_interface [ make ]                                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< urdf_interface ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf_interface   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> urdf_parser [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< urdf_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf_parser         
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> collada_parser [ make ]                                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< collada_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package collada_parser   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> urdf [ make ]                                          
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< urdf ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf                       
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> orocos_kdl [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< orocos_kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package orocos_kdl           
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> python_orocos_kdl [ make ]                             
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< python_orocos_kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package 
python_orocos_kdl
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> kdl [ make ]                                           
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package kdl
No Makefile in package kdl
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> kdl_parser [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< kdl_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package kdl_parser           
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbuild  No Makefile in package rosbuild              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib  No Makefile in package roslib                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosconsole  No Makefile in package rosconsole          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib             
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> angles [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles                   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pr2_mechanism_model [ make ]                           
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pr2_mechanism_model ROS_NOBUILD in package  
pr2_mechanism_model
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pr2_controller_interface [ make ]                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pr2_controller_interface ROS_NOBUILD in package  
pr2_controller_interface
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> bullet [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< bullet ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet                   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospy  No Makefile in package rospy                    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostest  No Makefile in package rostest                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roswtf  No Makefile in package roswtf                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                               
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_filters  No Makefile in package message_filters
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> tf [ make ]                                            
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf                           
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> nav_msgs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< nav_msgs  No Makefile in package nav_msgs              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> summit_xl_ctrl [ make ]                                
[ rosmake ] All 3 linessummit_xl_joystick: 0.2 se... [ 2 Active 28/70 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CMake Error: The source directory "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/summit_xl_sim  
/summit_xl_joystick" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package summit_xl_joystick written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/chengxiang/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121202-143919  
/summit_xl_joystick/build_output.log
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< summit_xl_joystick [FAIL] [ 0.33 seconds ]             
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package summit_xl_joystick. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] All 3 lines
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CMake Error: The source directory "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/summit_xl_sim
/summit_xl_ctrl" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package summit_xl_ctrl written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/chengxiang/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121202-143919 
/summit_xl_ctrl/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< summit_xl_ctrl [FAIL] [ 0.29 seconds ]                 
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package summit_xl_ctrl. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 30 packages with 2 failures.                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/chengxiang/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121202-143919
```

Does anyone here install Summit-xl before? In addition, how do you do install stacks from ROS, in general?  Thanks you.

Update1

After doing

```
rosws set --svn summit-xl-ros-stack http://summit-xl-ros-stack.googlecode.com
/svn/trunk/summit_xl_sim_fuerte
```

and

```
rosws update summit-xl-ros-stack
```

I get

```
chengxiang@ubuntu:~$ rosws set --svn summit-xl-ros-stack http://summit-xl-ros-
stack.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/summit_xl_sim_fuerte

     Change details of element (Use --merge-keep or --merge-replace to change):
  summit-xl-ros-stack   specified uri: http://code.google.com/p/summit-
xl-ros-stack -> http://summit-xl-ros-stack.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
/summit_xl_sim_fuerte;

Continue: (y)es, (n)o: y
Overwriting /home/chengxiang/sim_workspace/.rosinstall
Config changed, remember to run 'rosws update summit-xl-ros-stack' to update the 
folder from svn
chengxiang@ubuntu:~$ rosws update summit-xl-ros-stack
[summit-xl-ros-stack] Installing http://summit-xl-ros-stack.googlecode.com
/svn/trunk/summit_xl_sim_fuerte (version None) to /home/chengxiang/sim_workspace
/summit-xl-ros-stack
svn: URL 'http://summit-xl-ros-stack.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
/summit_xl_sim_fuerte' doesn't exist
Exception caught during install: Error processing 'summit-xl-ros-stack' : 
[summit- xl-ros-stack] Checkout of http://summit-xl-ros-stack.googlecode.com
/svn/trunk/summit_xl_sim_fuerte version None into /home/chengxiang/sim_workspace
/summit-xl-ros-stack failed.

ERROR: Error processing 'summit-xl-ros-stack' : [summit-xl-ros-stack] Checkout 
of http://summit-xl-ros-stack.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/summit_xl_sim_fuerte  
version None into /home/chengxiang/sim_workspace/summit-xl-ros-stack failed.
```

Update2

```
chengxiang@ubuntu:~/sim_workspace$ rosmake summit-xl-ros-stack 
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['summit-xl-ros-stack']                     
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/chengxiang/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output- 
20121204-230904
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['summit-xl-ros-stack'] to:
['summit_xl_description', 'summit_xl_odometry', 'summit_xl_tf', 
'summit_xl_2dnav', 'robotnik_worlds', 'summit_xl_sbpl_nav', 'explore_stage', 
'explore', 'summit_xl_joystick', 'summit_xl_ctrl']
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< geometry_msgs  No Makefile in package geometry_msgs    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< sensor_msgs  No Makefile in package sensor_msgs        
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> pr2_hardware_interface [ make ]                        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> summit_xl_joystick [ make ]                            
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< pr2_hardware_interface ROS_NOBUILD in package 
pr2_hardware_interface
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> colladadom [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< colladadom ROS_NOBUILD in package colladadom           
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> urdf_interface [ make ]                                
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< urdf_interface ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf_interface   
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> urdf_parser [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< urdf_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf_parser         
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> collada_parser [ make ]                                
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< collada_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package collada_parser   
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> urdf [ make ]                                          
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< urdf ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> orocos_kdl [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< orocos_kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package orocos_kdl           
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> python_orocos_kdl [ make ]                             
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< python_orocos_kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package  
python_orocos_kdl
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> kdl [ make ]                                           
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package kdl
 No Makefile in package kdl
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> kdl_parser [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< kdl_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package kdl_parser           
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosbuild  No Makefile in package rosbuild              
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslib  No Makefile in package roslib                  
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosconsole  No Makefile in package rosconsole          
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib             
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> angles [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles                   
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> pr2_mechanism_model [ make ]                           
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< pr2_mechanism_model ROS_NOBUILD in package 
pr2_mechanism_model
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> pr2_controller_interface [ make ]                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< pr2_controller_interface ROS_NOBUILD in package 
pr2_controller_interface
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> bullet [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< bullet ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet                   
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rospy  No Makefile in package rospy                    
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rostest  No Makefile in package rostest                
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roswtf  No Makefile in package roswtf                  
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                               
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< message_filters  No Makefile in package message_filters
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> tf [ make ]                                            
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf                           
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> nav_msgs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< nav_msgs  No Makefile in package nav_msgs              
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> summit_xl_ctrl [ make ]                                
[ rosmake ] All 3 linessummit_xl_joystick: 0.4 se... [ 2 Active 28/70 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 CMake Error: The source directory "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/summit_xl_sim
/summit_xl_joystick" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package summit_xl_joystick written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/chengxiang/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121204-230904
/summit_xl_joystick/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< summit_xl_joystick [FAIL] [ 0.38 seconds ]             
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package summit_xl_joystick. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] All 3 lines
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CMake Error: The source directory "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/summit_xl_sim 
/summit_xl_ctrl" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package summit_xl_ctrl written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/chengxiang/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121204-230904
/summit_xl_ctrl/build_output.log
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< summit_xl_ctrl [FAIL] [ 0.24 seconds ]                 
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package summit_xl_ctrl. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 30 packages with 2 failures.                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/chengxiang/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121204-230904
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49546/how-to-install-robotnik-summit-xl-stack?/) by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2012-12-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your directory structure suggests that you may have seen these instructions already, but just in case, you should refer to this [answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/36784/how-to-install-a-stack-and-package-manually-in-fuerte/?answer=36787#post-id-36787).

From the looks of the error message it seems that the provided zip file assumes that users will unzip it in the /opt/ros/fue.. I hope not though..

Quickly browsing the current versions of the code doesn't show anything strange.. so I'd suggested that you try checking out `http://summit-xl-ros-stack.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/trunk/summit_xl_sim_fuerte`.

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2012-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2012-12-02**:
Hi Trinighost, I tried checking out the URL you provided, but it doesn't seems to exist.Please see update 1.

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-12-03**:
updated... sorry about that.. I just "knew" that ...trunk/trunk... had to have been a mistake on my part.. oh well

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2012-12-04**:
It's alright. Well even after checking out from source,the error still exist.(Please see update 2) Does that mean I need to unzip the stack in opt/ros/fuerte/stacks? I tried that once, rosmake still fail though.

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-12-04**:
[./summit_xl_ctrl/Makefile](http://summit-xl-ros-stack.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/trunk/summit_xl_sim_fuerte/summit_xl_ctrl/Makefile) sets the CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR to `/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/summit_xl_sim/summit_xl_ctrl`... but this is autogenerated so this should be set in one of the parent folders